# jacoco not excluding classes when using ant

Tags: jacoco

I'm having trouble getting a jacoco/junit ant target to exclude classes from coverage.  I can get it to exclude packages though with something like this:

```
<jacoco:coverage destfile="${coverage.reports.dir.xml}/output.jacoco" excludes="foo.*:bar.fiz.*:my.long.package.name.*">
```

This doesn't exclude my test classes though because the test classes are in the same package as the classes they test. I've tired this to exclude the test classes with a regex, but it doesn't work.

```
<jacoco:coverage destfile="${coverage.reports.dir.xml}/output.jacoco" excludes="foo.*:bar.fiz.*:**/Test.*:**/Tests.*">
```

I also tried just including the classes I want in the report task, but since our test classes are in the same packages that doesn't work.  Our build puts all the classes in the same directory, like buildRoot/classes/ProjectName.  So buildRoot/classes/ProjectName/foo will contain the compiled classes for tests and non-test classes.

Any suggestions how how to get jacoco to exclude all tests in this setup?

thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Specifying classes with `jacoco:coverage` excludes them from coverage, so they show up as having 0% coverage in the report.

In order to also exclude these classes from the JaCoCo report, you need to use classfiles fileset task and exclude them in the `jacoco:report` ant task.

```
<jacoco:report>
  <executiondata>
    <file file="${coverage.reports.dir.xml}/merged-jacoco.exec"/>
  </executiondata>
  <structure name="Unit Tests ${unit.test.run.ts}">
    <classfiles>
      <fileset dir="${build.root}/classes/ProjectName/" >
        <exclude name="**/*Test*.class" />
      </fileset>
    </classfiles>
    <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
      <fileset dir="${src.root}/ProjectName/src/main"/>
    </sourcefiles>
  </structure>

  <html destdir="${coverage.reports.dir.html}"/>
</jacoco:report>
```

Comment: This was useful thanks. This is actually not documented fully on JaCoCo's website. This answer should be marked as correct.

Comment: If I could upvote this a million times I would. Have been tearing my hair out with trying to get the excludes working, and finally here is the answer I needed

Comment: Where do I find that file to make the changes in?