# Filter JaCoCo coverage reports with Gradle

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

## Problem:

I have a project with [jacoco](/questions/tagged/jacoco) and I want to be able to filter certain classes and/or packages.

## Related Documentation:

I have read the following documentation:

**Official [jacoco](/questions/tagged/jacoco) site:**
http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/index.html

**Official [jacoco](/questions/tagged/jacoco) docs for [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle):** https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

**Official [jacoco](/questions/tagged/jacoco) `Github` issues, working on coverage:**
https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/FilteringOptions
https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/14

## Related StackOverflow Links:

[JaCoCo & Gradle - Filtering Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625640/jacoco-gradle-filtering-options) (No answer)

[Exclude packages from Jacoco report using Sonarrunner and Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033757/exclude-packages-from-jacoco-report-using-sonarrunner-and-gradle) (Not using [sonar](/questions/tagged/sonar))

[JaCoCo - exclude JSP from report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682389/jacoco-exclude-jsp-from-report) (It seems to work for [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), I am using [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle))

[Maven Jacoco Configuration - Exclude classes/packages from report not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799419/maven-jacoco-configuration-exclude-classes-packages-from-report-not-working) (It seems to work for [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), I am using [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle))

[JaCoCo gradle plugin exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756014/jacoco-gradle-plugin-exclude) (Could not get this to work)

[Gradle Jacoco - coverage reports includes classes excluded in configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394427/gradle-jacoco-coverage-reports-includes-classes-excluded-in-configuration) (Seems very close, it used `doFirst`, did not work for me)

## Example of what I have tried:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml {
            enabled true // coveralls plugin depends on xml format report
        }

        html {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    test {
        jacoco {
            destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
            classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
            excludes = ["projecteuler/**"] // <-- does not work
            // excludes = ["projecteuler"]
        }
    }
}
```

## Question:

**How can I exclude certain packages and classes when generating the [jacoco](/questions/tagged/jacoco) coverage reports?**

Comment: A third party option (FD I'm founder of): If you upload reports to [Codecov](https://codecov.io) you can **ignore any files** you like after the fact in the features section of the product. Thanks.

Comment: @StevePeak So you can filter by `packages` online using `Codecov`? Also, I saw the `Github`, what about `Android` support, I saw `Java`. I should still have to send you all of the reports then filter after vs filtering before.

Comment: You can filter based on a regexp method of any filed you do not want to include. All java is supported via Jacoco reports. Just filtering after the fact on Codecov works. It will remember your filters and apply it to all future reports. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious; what does the `excludes` from the official documentation actually *do* then? Is it pretty much useless?

Comment: That `excludes` is not on the coverage task, but on the test task. It excludes files from being instrumented by JaCoCo and thus coverage being recorded. You can use this if you don't want to record coverage for some classes, if you cannot because of some conflict with another instrumenting agent, or because you pre-instrumented classes. This will not exclude a class from the report, especially in the last case mentioned, this would be a horrible idea.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

## Thanks to, `Yannick Welsch`:

After searching Google, reading the Gradle docs and going through older StackOverflow posts, I found this answer on the Official [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle) forums!

```
jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: 'com/blah/**')
        }))
    }
}
```

**Source:** https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2955

For older gradle versions < 5.x may need to use
`classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {` instead of `classDirectories.setFrom`

## Solution to my `build.gradle` for Java/Groovy projects:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml {
            enabled true // coveralls plugin depends on xml format report
        }

        html {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: ['codeeval/**',
                              'crackingthecode/part3knowledgebased/**',
                              '**/Chapter7ObjectOrientedDesign**',
                              '**/Chapter11Testing**',
                              '**/Chapter12SystemDesignAndMemoryLimits**',
                              'projecteuler/**'])
        })
    }
}
```

As you can see, I was successfully able to add more to `exclude:` in order to filter a few packages.

**Source:** https://github.com/jaredsburrows/CS-Interview-Questions/blob/master/build.gradle

## Custom tasks for other projects such as Android:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

task jacocoReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    reports {
        xml {
            enabled true // coveralls plugin depends on xml format report
        }

        html {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: ['codeeval/**',
                              'crackingthecode/part3knowledgebased/**',
                              '**/Chapter7ObjectOrientedDesign**',
                              '**/Chapter11Testing**',
                              '**/Chapter12SystemDesignAndMemoryLimits**',
                              'projecteuler/**'])
        })
    }
}
```

**Source:** https://github.com/jaredsburrows/android-gradle-java-app-template/blob/master/gradle/quality.gradle#L59

Comment: @BradPitcher No problem! It took me a while to find the right answer. It just seems so "hackish". I hope they come up with a nicer way.

Comment: So, what is the correct approach if I just want to exclude one class from package?

Comment: Something like: `exclude: ['**/*Test*.*'])`

Comment: I get the error  Gradle DSL method not found: 'jacocoTestReport()'. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Asker, It looks like you are not applying the plugin: `apply plugin: jacoco`.

Comment: I added apply plugin: 'jacoco' right after apply plugin: 'com.android.application'. I think it should be ok?

Comment: now I restarted Android studio and get the following Errow "Cannot get property 'files' on null object". Any ideas?

Comment: `jacocoTestReport` only works with both `jacoco` and `java` plugins. This is not for Android. Please see my repo here for android: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/android-gradle-java-template/blob/master/common.gradle#L160

Comment: @JaredBurrows Hi, thank you for your answer. How do i run my InstrumentationTests with this setup? They are saved in this folder "app\src\androidTest".

Comment: @JaredBurrows this link for android solution is broken. Can you please share it again or add it to your answer? Thanks

Comment: @sttaq Thanks. I added it in the answer and check it out here: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/android-gradle-java-app-template/blob/master/gradle/codeQuality.gradle#L49.

Comment: Side note - I've found that excluding `**/*Constants*.*` (using wildcard for extension) will exclude a file called `Constants.java` but `**/*Constants*.java` (explicitly providing the extension) will not.

Comment: In my case it is not ACTUALLY excluding them from calculation but it is just not showing them on the report. does it have to do under `beforeEvaluate` ?

Comment: The `classDirectories =` results in this warning. `The JacocoReportBase.setClassDirectories(FileCollection) method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0. Use getClassDirectories().from(...)`. It would be great to show a solution compatible with Gradle 6.0.

Comment: getting `Cannot set the value of read-only property 'classDirectories' for task ':jacocoTestReport' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport` using this configuration. Using gradle 5.6 and Java 8

Comment: More straightforward: replace `files.collect { fileTree(dir: it, exclude` with `.getAsFileTree().matching { exclude `

Answer (score 101):

For Gradle version 5.x, the `classDirectories = files(...)` gives a deprecation warning and does not work at all starting from Gradle 6.0
This is the nondeprecated way of excluding classes:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: 'com/exclude/**')
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simply use classDirectories.from (to append to the list instead of overriding list)

Comment: You will add `[]` after `exclude: ` to include several paths.

Comment: Excellent, I use gradle 6.0.1 and this solution worked for me.

Comment: this worked, can someone please explain what exactly is happening

Comment: I have changed the acccepted answer to reflect this change

Comment: Or, even, use `getClassDirectories().from()`.

Comment: I am trying to exclude my dtos and i am using the below code. But it is not working Please let me know if i am missing anything here. Tried in build.gradle                                                                                    jacocoTestReport {
  afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: '**/dto/**')
        }))
 }
   }

Comment: If `afterEvaluate` necessary?

Answer (score 25):

for me, it's fine working with

```
test {
  jacoco {
    excludes += ['codeeval/**',
                 'crackingthecode/part3knowledgebased/**',
                 '**/Chapter7ObjectOrientedDesign**',
                 '**/Chapter11Testing**',
                 '**/Chapter12SystemDesignAndMemoryLimits**',
                 'projecteuler/**']
  }
}
```

as stated out in documentation
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#N16E62 and initally asked
so the answer is:

so if you ask me: it's not a question of

```
excludes = ["projecteuler/**"]
```

or

```
excludes += ["projecteuler/**"]
```

but

```
excludes = ["**/projecteuler/**"]
```

to exclude a package `*.projecteuler.*`

and `test {}` on project level, not nested in `jacocoTestReport`

Comment: This seems to give the classes 0% coverage rather than omit them altogether. I'm using JaCoCi 0.8.5 and Gradle 6.0

Comment: This the right way to tell jacoco to not meddle with some classes, other approaches only affect the reporting part.

Answer (score 16):

for Kotlin users, here is what I used (gradle 6.7)

build.gradle.kts

```
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    // tests are required to run before generating the report
    dependsOn(tasks.test) 
    // print the report url for easier access
    doLast {
        println("file://${project.rootDir}/build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html")
    }
    classDirectories.setFrom(
        files(classDirectories.files.map {
            fileTree(it) {
                exclude("**/generated/**", "**/other-excluded/**")
            }
        })
    )
}
```

as suggested here : https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1176#issuecomment-610643709

Answer (score 15):

For Gradle6
Use something like below, because they made `classDirectories as final`, we cannot re-assign it, but a setter method exists `classDirectories.setFrom` which can be utilized

```
    jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        html.destination file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: ['**/server/**',
                              '**/model/**',
                              '**/command/**'
                    ]
            )
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use the below snippet in build.gradle to exclude my dtos but it is not working. I am using gradle 6.6.1 version. Let me know if any changes  jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        html.destination file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: ['**/dto/**'
                    ]
            )
        }))
    }
}

Answer (score 14):

In order to filter in jacoco report, exclusion need to be done in two task `jacocoTestReport` and `jacocoTestCoverageVerification`.

sample code

```
    def jacocoExclude = ['**/example/**', '**/*Module*.class']

    jacocoTestReport {
        afterEvaluate {
            getClassDirectories().setFrom(classDirectories.files.collect {
                fileTree(dir: it, exclude: jacocoExclude)
            })
        }
    }

    jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
        afterEvaluate {
            getClassDirectories().setFrom(classDirectories.files.collect {
                fileTree(dir: it, exclude: jacocoExclude)
            })
        }

        ...
    }
```

Comment: actually (at least with Gradle 7.x) you don't need to set the exclusion for `jacocoTestCoverageVerification`

Comment: Variable can be avoided if we say `classDirectories.setFrom(tasks.jacocoTestReport.classDirectories)`

Answer (score 8):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404790/jacoco-not-excluding-classes-when-using-ant) is a solution for this problem in ANT. This can be adapted to gradle by adding the following under the `jacocoTestReport` task. Although this isn't really documented by jacoco, it seems like the only way to filter the test results for now.

```
afterEvaluate {
    classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
        fileTree(dir: it, exclude: 'excluded/files/**')
    })
}
```

Comment: Alright, thank you for confirming that my findings are correct! I hope they make it easier to filter in the future or simply document how to filter using Gradle.

Comment: Is there any way to exclude a source set from inclusion in jacoco report? I want to exclude all source files which are located in `generated/java/` instead of `main/java`.

Comment: This won't work for a clean build. afterEvaluate runs in Gradle's configuration phase which is before any tasks have executed and before any classes have been compiled. So the classes dirs will be empty

Answer (score 7):

For those who still scratching their heads to filter certain packages from the coverage report, here is the configuration that works for me using the most recent libraries.

```
   Build tool: Gradle 6.5 (also tried for 6.7)
   Coverage Tool: Jacoco 0.8.5
```

Things to consider/Justifications

- `afterScript` is not required
- Need to exclude it twice, one for report generation and coverage verification
- The intellij IDE recommends to use `excludes` param instead of `exclude`. Either of which just works fine
- While providing the regex, be sure to provide the `.class` files and not the `.java` files.
- Post Gradle 5, `classDirectories` is a read-only field, therefore, use `classDirectories.setFrom`

```
jacocoTestReport {
    doLast {
        println("See report file://${project.rootDir}/build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html")
    }
    excludedClassFilesForReport(classDirectories)
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    excludedClassFilesForReport(classDirectories)
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.55
            }
        }
    }
}

private excludedClassFilesForReport(classDirectories) {
    classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
        fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [
                '**/common/apigateway/*.class',
                '**/common/*/client/*Client*.class',
                '**/configuration/*ClientConfiguration.class',
                '**/model/search/*SearchService.class'
        ])
    }))
}

check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

Comment: Private method can be avoided via `classDirectories.setFrom(tasks.jacocoTestReport.classDirectories)`

Answer (score 5):

This has been out for a while, but I just ran across this.  I was struggling with all the exclusions needed.  I found it was something much more simple for me.  If you follow the Maven project layout style /src/main/java and /src/test/java, you simply need to put **buildDir/classes/*main***  in your **classDirectories** config like so:

```
afterEvaluate {
    jacocoTestReport {
        def coverageSourceDirs = ['src/main/java']
        reports {
            xml.enabled false
            csv.enabled false
            html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacocoHtml"
        }
        sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
        classDirectories = fileTree(
                dir: "${project.buildDir}/classes/main",
                excludes: [
                      //whatever here like JavaConfig etc. in /src/main/java
                     ]
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Just saw this again.  This was taken directly from a working config.  Perhaps your version of Gradle and Jacoco were different than mine.  Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

The code below excludes classes from coverage verification as well:

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/classes/main",
                    exclude: ['**/packagename/**'])
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, your version throws the following exception message: "Cannot set the value of read-only property 'classDirectories'".

Fixed with change classDirectories -> classDirectories.from

.But unfortunately my package still exists inside of the report

Answer (score 5):

For anyone going out of their mind looking for this answer in Kotlin DSL, here it is:

```kotlin
val jacocoExclude = listOf("**/entities/**", "**/dtos/**")
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.isEnabled = true
        csv.isEnabled = false
    }
    classDirectories.setFrom(classDirectories.files.map {
        fileTree(it).matching {
            exclude(jacocoExclude)
        }
        })
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty("gradle.build.dir", project.buildDir)
    finalizedBy(jacocoTestReport)
    extensions.configure(JacocoTaskExtension::class) {
        excludes = jacocoExclude
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, i have to do exclude in 2 places

```
jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report


    afterEvaluate {
        excludedClassFilesForReport(classDirectories)
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {

    afterEvaluate {
        excludedClassFilesForReport(classDirectories)
    }
}

private excludedClassFilesForReport(classDirectories) {
    classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
        fileTree(dir: it,
            exclude: [
                    'com/test/a/config/**',
                    'com/test/b/constant/**',
                    'com/test/c/MainApp.class'
            ]
    )
}))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

some comments mentioned the deprecation warning.  to solve just use the getter:

```
afterEvaluate {
    getClassDirectories().from(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
        fileTree(dir: it, exclude: 'com/blah/**')
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working config in Gradle with Jacoco 0.8.5 :

```
def jacocoExclusions = [
        '**/config/*Config.class',
        '**/config/*Advice.class',
        '**/security/*AuthorityRoles.class',
        '**/*Application.class'
];

jacocoTestReport {
  reports {
    xml.enabled false
    csv.enabled false
    html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacocoHtml")
  }
  afterEvaluate {
    classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
      fileTree(dir: it,
              exclude: jacocoExclusions
      )
    }))
  }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
  afterEvaluate {
    classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
      fileTree(dir: it,
              exclude: jacocoExclusions
      )
    }))
  }
  violationRules {
    rule {
      excludes = jacocoExclusions
      limit {
        minimum = 0.90
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 6.8.3 thrown an exception.
`Cannot set the value of read-only property 'classDirectories' for task ':jacocoTestReport' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.`

so I found a way to fix the issue by using

```
classDirectories.setFrom(
            fileTree(dir: "build/classes/java/main")
                    .filter({file -> !file.path.contains('/dir1')})
                    .filter({file -> !file.path.contains('/dir2')})
                    .filter({file -> !file.path.contains('/dir3')})
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle 7.6.1 in Kotlin syntax this works for me (using `setExcludes` instead of `exclude`)

```
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        html.required.set(true)
        xml.required.set(true)
    }
    classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.map {
        fileTree(it) {
            setExcludes(listOf(
                    "**/first/path/to/skip/*.class",
                    "**/second/path/to/skip/*.class"
            ))
        }
    }))
}
```

Comment: Hi. Whats your Jacoco version ? Im facing an issue this is my code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77514743/cannot-obtain-expected-coverage-report-by-excluding-classes-and-packages-using-j

Comment: This is Jacoco in version 0.8.8. 
I didn't set this version explicitly, I left it for gradle to figure it out