# How not to run a particular test when executing connectedAndroidTest?

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, android-instrumentation

It takes long to execute some of our instrumented tests. So I'd like not to run them when I run all the other instrumented tests with `gradle connectedAndroidTest`.

Why don't I annotate those tests with [@Ignore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html)? Because I'd like to run them later using `adb shell` as described [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html)
Like this:

> Running all tests except those in a particular class: adb shell am
>   instrument -w -e notClass com.android.foo.FooTest
>   com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

If I marked those tests ignored and compiled them, it wouldn't be possible to execute them at all.

Is it possible to modify `connectedAndroidTest` or some other task to reach what I need?

Comment: In my experience you cannot modify connectedAndroidTest task. You need to create a custom gradle task and adapt it to your goals.

Comment: annotation from cucumber features files can trigger tests in your favor. Not sure you will be interested in that area.

Comment: @WenChao, please post your code