# How do I create my own configuration block with a Gradle script plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Our company has a Gradle script plugin with a number of tasks in it. For instance, it includes the Jacoco `afterEvaluate` block from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29887806/531762):

```
def pathsToExclude = ["**/*Example*"]

jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: pathsToExclude)
        })
    }
}
```

We would like to take that `pathsToExclude` variable and define that in our `build.gradle` file and have the rest of the logic in a script plugin (let's call it `company-script-plugin.gradle`. For instance:

```
apply from: http://example.com/company-script-plugin.gradle

companyConfiguration {
    pathsToExclude = ["**/*Example*"]
}
```

Our initial thought was to add a task in the build script so that we could get a `companyConfiguration`

```
task companyConfiguration {
    ext.pathsToExclude = []
}
```

However, we think that this is a hacky workaround because running the task doesn't do anything. What is the proper way to create my own configuration block?

We'd like it to be as simple as possible, and to be a script plugin (rather than binary plugin) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here you've an example how it can be done:

```
apply plugin: CompanyPlugin

companyConfiguration {
  pathsToExclude = ['a', 'b', 'c']
}

class CompanyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  void apply(Project p) {
    println "Plugin ${getClass().simpleName} applied"
    p.extensions.create('companyConfiguration', CompanyConfigurationExtension, p)
  }

}

class CompanyConfigurationExtension {
  List<String> pathsToExclude

  CompanyConfigurationExtension(Project p) {
  }

}

task printCompanyConfiguration {
  doLast {
    println "Path to exclide $companyConfiguration.pathsToExclude"
  }
}
```

Also, please have a look at the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:mapping_extension_properties_to_task_properties).

Comment: It's not clear to me how this works with a script plugin. I tried `apply from: "company-script-plugin.gradle"` followed by `apply plugin: CompanyPlugin`, but got "Could not get unknown property 'CompanyPlugin'". Am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: @Thunderforge, just add the `CompanyPlugin` to `company-script-plugin.gradle` file and leave `apply from: ...` block only.