# Jacoco - How to exclude inherited class in jacoco Android gradle

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

Hello how can I exclude all my inherited classes from Jacoco report Coverage.
for example- I have a BaseActivity and multiple sub Activity  for Example A,B,C.
And I want to exclude the report of all the subActivities.

I have multiple sub Activity so that I can not write the name of All these subActivities to exclude in gradle file, so is there any way that if I will just give the name of Parent Activity in gradle and all the subActivities name will exclude from  the jacoco report.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible, since there are no such a filtering option yet. You can see them [here](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/FilteringOptions).

As per my point of view, the only way you can do it by filtering your sub-classes by name of the class or some package, which contains you sub-classes. Sure, for that you must name all your sub-classes with some specific name.

How to filer coverage by names you can read  in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887805/filter-jacoco-coverage-reports-with-gradle). You just need to modify `jacocoTestReport` task configuration to exclude some classes or packages as follows:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    ...

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: ['codeeval/**',
                              'crackingthecode/part3knowledgebased/**',
                              '**/Chapter7ObjectOrientedDesign**',
                              '**/Chapter11Testing**'])
        })
    }
}
```