# Exclude package from Jacoco coverage in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

Trying to exclude packages from coverage report as my Jenkins pipeline fail. I have a sub project with all POJO:s. I don't want to write uittest for all these. Hence, they will drag down branch/line coverage som that coverage will be below threshold and fail my build.

It should be possible to exclude some packages, but I cant get it to work.

I have the following jacoco.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'  
apply plugin: 'java'  
jacoco {  
  toolVersion = "0.8.2"  
}  

jacocoTestReport {  
reports {  
  xml.enabled true  
  csv.enabled false  
  html.enabled true  
}  

afterEvaluate {  
  classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {  
     fileTree(dir: it, exclude: '**xxx/yyy/zzz/**')  
  })  
}  

task coverage { dependsOn 'jacocoTestReport' }  

check.dependsOn 'jacocoTestReport'
```

---

The following in my sonar.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'  

sonarqube {  
properties {  
  property "sonar.forceAnalysis", "true"  
  property "sonar.forceAuthentication", "true"  
  property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"  
  property "sonar.login", ""  
  property "sonar.password", ""  
 }  
}  

subprojects {  
 sonarqube {  
  properties {  
     property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", 
 "$buildDir/reports/jacoco/allTests.exec"
     property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "$buildDir/test-results/test"  
  }  
 }  
}  

task sonar { dependsOn 'sonarqube' }
```

---

In my build.gradle:

```
apply from: 'gradle/sonar.gradle'  
...  
apply plugin: 'java'  
...  
subprojects {  
  apply from: '../gradle/jacoco.gradle'   
  ...  
}
```

---

And finally from my Jenkins file:

```
step([$class: 'JacocoPublisher', changeBuildStatus: false, 
 exclusionPattern: '**/*Test*.class', inclusionPattern: 
 '**/*.class', minimumBranchCoverage: '80', sourcePattern: '**/src'])  

try {  
 dir(BUILD_DIR) {  
 sh './gradlew sonar'  
}
```

---

But still the xxx.yyy.zzz Is generated in the coverage report in Jenkins!

Comment: Why backslashing your `*` ? Just set `**xxx/yyy/zzz/**`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter JaCoCo coverage reports with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887805/filter-jacoco-coverage-reports-with-gradle)

Comment: Sorry, the backslash was needed before I added code style. I do net have the backslash in my code. I have updated the question now.

Comment: @Dezso Gabos I have seen the solution in the link, but I think it is identical to what I have. Still Jenkins/Jacoco will not exclude the package.

Comment: `sonar.coverage.exclusion` to remove coverage for special classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally got it working! The key is the JacocoPuplisher.

```
step([$class: 'JacocoPublisher', changeBuildStatus: false, exclusionPattern: 
'**/xxx/yyy/zzz/**/*.class, **/*Test*.class', inclusionPattern: '**/*.class', 
minimumBranchCoverage: '80', sourcePattern: '**/src'])
```

This is the only way to I get it to work with Jenkins.

Setting the sonar.coverage.exclusion or using the afterEvalueate stuff above has no effect.

Comment: can u please share your entire file content where u have put this snippet of JacocoPublisher?? @user1578293

Comment: hah, dude... I wasted a lot of days to find a solution. This piece of sht is really could not work with the inner config. But your code is working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to accomplish file/package exclusions from the `jacoco()` Jenkins pipeline plugin ( which in our standard Jenkinsfile gets called in `pipeline { ... post { ... always {` ) by just adding directly to the  plugin invocation arguments like so:

```
...
    post {
        always {
            ...
            // Change the exclusion for the jacoco() jenkins plugin to exclude testutils package. 
            jacoco(exclusionPattern: '**/testutils/**,**/*Test*.class')
```

It seems one of the big confusions in this whole topic is that there is a `jacocoTestReport` gradle target, which has its own exclusion syntax, and then this `jacoco()` Jenkins pipeline task which seems totally independent. Sonar coverage exclusion looks like maybe a 3rd thing?