# Exclude unit tests from code coverage analysis with JaCoCo

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I am using JaCoCo with Gradle. Is there any way to exclude some unit tests from code coverage analysis of tested code? (Note that I do not mean hiding unit tests or some classes from the coverage report, which was discussed in, e.g., [Filter JaCoCo coverage reports with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29887805/9105334)).

I have some test which is for a kind of consistency check of a necessary condition, in other words, the test is *weak*; the test is expected to most likely pass in any way. If it fails the tested code definitely has a certain type of a bug, but even if it passes it can't guarantee that the code is completely right (this should be checked by another *stronger* test, which is taken into account for code coverage). So surely I would like to run this unit test in `gradle test`, but do not like to include it for code coverage analysis of the tested code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different Gradle tasks for different types of tests. For example

`src/main/java/Example.java`

```
class Example {
    void weak() {
        System.out.println("weak");
    }

    void strong() {
        System.out.println("strong");
    }
}
```

`src/test/java/StrongTest.java`

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class StrongTest {
    @Test
    public final void test() {
        new Example().strong();
    }
}
```

`src/test/java/WeakTest.java`

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class WeakTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        new Example().weak();
    }
}
```

and finally `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
}

test {
    exclude 'WeakTest.class'
}

task weakTest(type: Test) {
    include 'WeakTest.class'
}

check.dependsOn weakTest
```

Default `test` task will execute everything except `WeakTest` and will use JaCoCo to collect execution information into `build/jacoco/test.exec`.

Custom `weakTest` task will execute only `WeakTest` and will use JaCoCo to collect execution information into `build/jacoco/weakTest.exec`.

Default `jacocoTestReport` will use information from `build/jacoco/test.exec` for generation of HTML report.

So that execution of

```
gradle clean build jacocoTestReport
```

using Gradle 6.2.1 will generate the following report in directory `build/reports/jacoco/test/html/` that doesn't contain information about execution of `WeakTest`

[image: report]

Comment: Nice.. but that doesn't answer the question - The person wants to be able to skip *unit tests* - i.e. individual tests - not entire classes.

Comment: Given that answer was accepted by the author, IMO it does answer the question ;)