# JacocoTestReport exclude files in gradle7.1.1

Tags: gradle, jacoco

Below is the code snippet I'm using in gradle 7.1.1 and Jacoco version 0.8.4 and getting a build error

> Could not find method setFrom() for arguments [file collection] on main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.

```
jacocoTestReport {
group = "Reporting"
reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.enabled true
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco"
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                exclude: [
                          ''
                          ]
            )
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue with Gradle 7.X.X?

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the version of gradle you used.

you can check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887805/filter-jacoco-coverage-reports-with-gradle), it describes this problem in every detail

I encounter the same exception when running a unit test, using gradle-4.10.

Solve the problem when I used gradle-7.2